# PHP - Language Switch - MVC Framework - Session or Javascript (i18next library) based? Whats better?

Tags: javascript, php, session, internationalization

I cant realy decide what has the better advantages for the way switching
language in my app done within my own mvc framework.

**Session Based**

GET Variable "lang" sets the Session param "LANGUAGE_FILE" to desired language
and will load a language file over the controller `$this->language->load(Session::get("LANGUAGE_FILE"));`
Later in code, used as `<p><?=$lang["page_title"]?></p>`

or

**Javascript Based (using i18next library)**

Click on the Button sets the Cookie and loads the desired language via Javascript from a json file.

```
i18n.init({
    resGetPath: 'assets/locales/__lng__.json',
    load: 'unspecific',
    debug: true,
    useCookie: true,
    fallbackLng : false
}, function () {
    $('body').i18n();
});
```

Which later in code can be used as following

```
<p data-i18n="page.main.title"></p>
```

The only difference I can see is that with Session it would need the page to reload, with javascript it would directly translate.

What shall I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I would include the language into the URL.
Example:

```
www.yourdomain.com/de/yourpage
```

Where "de" stands for german. 
If you switch the language, just redirect to a different URL. This has the advantage that everybody that hits this url sees it in the same language. Including Google, which is very important for SEO.

Comment: That sounds pretty good. For Google it is not important, since the app is only available to registered users activated by support/administration.